# HTML Video tag not updating source on re render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

I have a react component that renders 2 `<video>` elements.

At any time only 1 element is visible and there is some logic that updates the state so these toggles.

I have an array of ids and on each render of the state/player toggle, I would like to update the playing video with a random video.

(I have added a button to toggle the state for the sake of this question)

**If I log out my state in the render method I can see the `url` prop is updated as expected, however the video does not change source.**

I am choosing to toggle the `visibility` of the element as `display:none` or something like

```
{playerOne.visible &&
    <LandingPageVideoPlayer url={playerOne.url} />
}
```

causes a flashing when the state is re-rendered.

**I can't work out how to change the source of the video element on re-render.**

**Components**

```
const LandingPageVideoPlayer = ({ url, isActive }) => {
  const playerClassName = `video-player ${isActive ? 'video-player--is-active' : null}`

  return (
    <video className={playerClassName} autoPlay loop muted>
      <source src={url} type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
  )
}
class LandingPage extends Component {

  MOCK_URL_SOURCE = [
    'ehZqNokVylyWk',
    'hDqq4LalRAUiQ',
    'yjTccXlnh6LXW',
    '3FjEPbKqEPhPpmC8uY',
    '3ohs7NLUXtNW98mtIQ'
  ]

  state = {
    playerOne: {
      visible: true,
      url: `https://media0.giphy.com/media/3ohs7NLUXtNW98mtIQ/giphy.mp4`
    },
    playerTwo: {
      visible: false,
      url: `https://media0.giphy.com/media/3FjEPbKqEPhPpmC8uY/giphy.mp4`
    }
  }

  randomItem = () => {
    return this.MOCK_URL_SOURCE[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.MOCK_URL_SOURCE.length)]
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      playerOne: { visible: !prevState.playerOne.visible, url: `https://media0.giphy.com/media/${this.randomItem()}/giphy.mp4` },
      playerTwo: { visible: !prevState.playerTwo.visible, url: `https://media0.giphy.com/media/${this.randomItem()}/giphy.mp4` }
    }))
  }

  render() {
    const { playerOne, playerTwo } = this.state

    if (!playerOne || !playerTwo) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <div className='landing-page'>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}></button>
        <LandingPageVideoPlayer url={playerOne.url} isActive={playerOne.visible} />
        <LandingPageVideoPlayer url={playerTwo.url} isActive={playerTwo.visible} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LandingPage
```

**Video Player SCSS**

```
  .video-player {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    visibility: hidden;

    &--is-active {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

React doesn't know which video to update unless `key` property for each video is provided.

So when you set the key prop for the video to something unique, say `url` pass to the player, it should work.

```
const LandingPageVideoPlayer = ({ url, isActive }) => {
  const playerClassName = `video-player ${
    isActive ? "video-player--is-active" : null
  }`;

  return (
         .....  .....
    <video key={url} className={playerClassName} autoplay loop muted>
      <source src={url} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  );
};
```

Check out the working demo.
[image: Edit so.answer.57235013]

For more information how the key property works, check out the official documentation [List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

The first sentence reads,

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

In your case, you have two videos (which is actually a list of two items), so to help React which video has changed, `key` would help React to identify which video has changed.

Comment: Perfect :) thank you so much that makes complete sense

Answer (score 1):

> add key={this.state.url} like this

```
<div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-8">
                        <video width="720" key={this.state.url} height="540" controls >
                            <source src={this.state.url} type="video/mp4" />

                        </video>
                        <h1>{this.state.url}</h1>
```